# Customise Kendo dropdownlist message to replace "no data found"

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In our .NET Core 3 web app, we're using Kendo with our razor views.

We're using an `Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor` control which, when it has no data to display, shows the text:

"NO DATA FOUND"

We want to replace this string with a custom message.   We know we can replace the string in `kendo.all.min.js`, but we're aware this would get overwritten once we update Kendo.

How can we specify the text string programatically, within the `DropDownListFor` control itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup and assign a template to use and customize the no data message. I have also added the span with a style to remove the upper case text-transform that Kendo adds. Like so:

```
<!-- Template -->
<script id="noDataTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span style="text-transform: none;">
        <strong>My Custom No Data Message here</strong>
    </span>
</script>

<!-- DropDownList initialization -->
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("customers")
            .DataTextField("ContactName")
            .DataValueField("CustomerID")
            .NoDataTemplateId("noDataTemplate") // Reference to the template.
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("Template_GetCustomers", "ComboBox");
                });
            })
)
```

More information here: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/editors/dropdownlist/templates#no-data-templates

Comment: Thanks for your answer @G_P.    This nearly does what what we want, but the text "My Custom No Data Message" is always rendered IN UPPER CASE.   How can we display it exactly as we specify in that template?

Comment: It looks like the Kendo control may be adding text-transform styling to upper case the text. If you add the following style to a span around your custom text does it prevent it? text-transform: none;

Comment: @ArtieLeech now that I'm back at a computer, it looks like Kendo adds the .k-nodata class, which contains the text-transform: uppercase  So, doing what I said above where you add the text-transform: none style should work for you

Comment: That's perfect now, thanks @G_P!    Do you want to update your answer to include the correct span, for others seeing this post?
 <span style="text-transform: none;">My Custom No Data Message here</span>

Comment: Glad it worked out for you - I updated the answer to include the span with style override

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to create a JS file for your project and overwrite any message you want, so you can update kendo without any problem.

Now, to anwser your question, in case of `DropDownList` you can change the value of the following property like this:

```
kendo.ui.DropDownList.prototype.options.messages.noData = 'Sorry, no data here';
```

You can do that with any other widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which may be helpful for us in other scenarios.  But in this scenario, we wanted to add attributes to specific DropDownListFor controls, in the view itself.